# How do I break links when using Excel with win32com in Python?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

How do I break links when using Excel with win32com in Python? I have looked around and I have this code, but it gives me an error saying that the remote procedure call failed.

```
wb.BreakLink(Name=path_to_linked_wb, Type=1)
```

Comment: There is an example at the bottom of the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.breaklink
My suggestion as a test would be to iterate over `wb.LinkSources(1)` and get the actual names of the links, as you may be getting Name wrong.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution yet for this? I tried breaking link one by one as per above mentioned example. Yet in one of the links, the RPC fails throwing an exception.